# Input Loop - Dictionary Lookup and Recursion Calculator in Python

Tags: python, loops, calculator

brand new at Python, and been experimenting with various calculator code methods in Python.

I found the following code:

```
from operator import pow, truediv, mul, add, sub  

operators = {
  '+': add,
  '-': sub,
  '*': mul,
  '/': truediv
}

def calculate(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)
    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = s.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))

calc = input("Type calculation:\n")
print("Answer: " + str(eval(calc)))
```

and I'm just wondering how one would formulate an input loop for this one.

Comment: Hi, If this is not your original code, it's a good habit to please link the original source.

Comment: You are write. My apologies. I found the code on this site: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/3-ways-to-write-a-calculator-in-python-61642f2e4a9a

Answer (score 0):

The script will ask you continuosly for operation to compute as follows:

```
while True:
    calc = input("Type calculation (C to exit):\n")
    if calc.upper().strip() == "C":
        break
    print("Answer: " + str(eval(calc)))
```

Note that, as it is, the code is extremely fragile, given that anything which cannot be reconducted to a *number operator number* pattern (or "C"), will need to be treated. You could use pattern matching to check if the operation is valid before passing to `eval` first, and manage bad cases as you wish.

Comment: I see what you mean. With this loop in place, if I type in anything that isn't a valid operation, it gives me an error but continues to run. I guess alternatively, I could put the loop in place for anything that is a valid calculation, but create a sort of 'press any key to exit' exit strategy? 

Meaning, anything that isn't a "valid" calculation would exit the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import pow, truediv, mul, add, sub  

operators = {
  '+': add,
  '-': sub,
  '*': mul,
  '/': truediv
}

def calculate(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)
    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = s.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))
cont = 'y'
while cont.lower() == 'y':
    calc = input("Type calculation:\n")        
    print("Answer: " + str(eval(calc)))
    cont = input("Do you want to continue? (y/n)")
```

It would be good to add more validations to the code... like ensuring that only one operator exists and that there are numbers on either side of the operator inside the calc function.

Also, you are importing power but don't have a symbol for it. Can use '^' if you haven't already? It is easier than using '**' which python uses.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that pow was imported but not utilised! Thank you for pointing that out. I also really like the idea of prompting for a yes or no to continue.